# Leleetcode ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow

Tags: c

I am practicing the Leetcode question "Cells in a Range on an Excel Sheet".

Here is the problem:

A cell (r, c) of an excel sheet is represented as a string "<col><row>" where:

- <col> denotes the column number c of the cell. It is represented by alphabetical letters. For example, the 1st column is denoted by 'A', the 2nd by 'B', the 3rd by 'C', and so on.
- <row> is the row number r of the cell. The rth row is represented by the integer r.
- You are given a string s in the format "<col1><row1>:<col2><row2>", where <col1> represents the column c1, <row1> represents the row r1, <col2> represents the column c2, and <row2> represents the row r2, such that r1 <= r2 and c1 <= c2.

Return the list of cells (x, y) such that r1 <= x <= r2 and c1 <= y <= c2. The cells should be represented as strings in the format mentioned above and be sorted in non-decreasing order first by columns and then by rows.

This is my code:

```c
/**
* Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().
*/
char ** cellsInRange (char * s, int* returnSize)
{
    char **a = (char **) malloc (sizeof (char*) * 300);
    int u = 0;
    int up = s[1] - '0';
    int down = s[4] - '0';
    int left = s[0] - 'A';
    int right = s[3] - 'A';

    for (int i = left; i <= right; i++) {
        for (int j = up; j <= down; j++) {
            char p[2];

            char e = j + '0';
            char d = i + 'A';
            p[0] = d;
            p[1] = e;

            strcpy (a[u], p);
            u++;
        }
    }
    *returnSize = u;
    return a;
}
```

Then I got an error:

```
==42==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address 0x7fffc1b03402 at pc 0x7f464e481060 bp 0x7fffc1b03370 sp 0x7fffc1b02b18
READ of size 7 at 0x7fffc1b03402 thread T0
    #0 0x7f464e48105f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x9c05f)
    #3 0x7f464d8ad0b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
Address 0x7fffc1b03402 is located in stack of thread T0 at offset 34 in frame
  This frame has 1 object(s):
    [32, 34) 'p' <== Memory access at offset 34 overflows this variable
HINT: this may be a false positive if your program uses some custom stack unwind mechanism, swapcontext or vfork
      (longjmp and C++ exceptions *are* supported)
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x9c05f) 
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x100078358630: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x100078358640: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x100078358650: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x100078358660: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x100078358670: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 f1 f1 f1 f1
=>0x100078358680:[02]f2 f2 f2 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x100078358690: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 f1 f1 f1 f1 04 f2 f2 f2
  0x1000783586a0: f2 f2 f2 f2 00 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 f2 00 f2 f2 f2
  0x1000783586b0: f2 f2 f2 f2 04 f2 f2 f2 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1000783586c0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1000783586d0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
==42==ABORTING
```

How to deal with it?
Sorry if structured poorly this is my first question any help and all feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Read man-page for `strcpy ()`.

Comment: You strcpy into a[u], but a[u] is an uninitialized pointer. And the string you're copying is not null-terminated.

Comment: You allocate an array of character pointers for `a` but never point those pointers anywhere.  You could malloc space for the strings those pointers point to or you could use strdup instead of strcpy.  Either way, you need to terminate the string in `p` before you do anything with it.